# Rails error - attribute not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some JSON I am working with in an instance variable called stream. I am trying to use it like this:

```
user = stream.for_user # user model
```

Here is the contents of stream:

```
=> #<User _id: 4f8de8c40a5dcd0d1d00004c, agency_requested: [], encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FPVJDLkkD6AXd5SY/hL6KeuC6QR6vfU3OKI3oGCPxrTiEnAwvGOOu", avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_file_name: nil, agreed_to_terms: ["v1"], location: nil, last_name_first_initial: "Genadinik, A.", first_initial_last_name: "A. Genadinik", legacy_blogger_id: nil, created_at: Tue Apr 17 22:03:50 UTC 2012, active_advertiser_id: nil, avatar_source: :default, agency_roles: [], last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_sent_at: Tue Apr 17 22:03:50 UTC 2012, created_via: "CMPLY-WEB", deleted_at: nil, updated_at: Fri May 11 16:37:16 UTC 2012, last_sign_in_at: Thu May 10 20:48:53 UTC 2012, display_welcome_help: true, program_influencers: [], agency_rep: true, account_type: :influencer, legacy_user_id: nil, sign_in_count: 44, _type: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, programs: [], active_agency_id: nil, account_status: :active, admin_roles: [], legacy_password: nil, gets_newsletter: false, full_name: "Alex Genadinik", last_name: "Genadinik", reset_password_token: nil, current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", authentication_token: "ViQ5q89n39zyyVUT3wLp", user_name: "me_n0_like_scrennames", time_zone: "Chihuahua", bio: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, current_sign_in_at: Fri May 11 16:37:16 UTC 2012, confirmation_token: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, last_name_first_name: "Genadinik, Alex", agency_id: nil, first_name: "Alex", confirmed_at: Tue Apr 17 22:49:28 UTC 2012, email: "alex@cmp.ly">
```

I get an error that the attribute I am using is not found.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `for_user' for #<User:0x138be12a0>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:166:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/lib/app/monitoring/parsers/linked_in_parser.rb:40:in `fetch!'
    from (irb):18
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Flexoid i am trying to make the user instance variable reflect the user structure of the json

Comment: Why do you expect `for_user` to be there? Is it defined in your User model?

Comment: `stream` is an instance of th `User` class, according to the it's content output. Where is JSON you trying to use?

Comment: Possibly I asked too stupid of a question...I am myself too confused :)

Comment: The stream is an object representing a user  and I am just trying to assign it to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user = stream.try(:for_user)

The try method is good in situations like this where it might not always be populated.

Comment: There's no problem with an unexpected `nil` here, so this will result in the exact same error.

Comment: @moger777 just tried it and still got the same error NoMethodError: undefined method `for_user' for #<User:0x131331918>